Choosing the number of bins in denscomp?
Is it possible to choose the number of bins when using denscomp from fitdistrplus?
I have a sample of 33 values. If I want to build a histogram with 6 bins there is no problem:
hist(q, breaks = seq(min(q), max(q), length.out = 7))

I’ve adjusted a Gumbel distribution for the sample, using fitdistrplus/fitdist:
rez_gumbel <- fitdist(q, "gumbel", 
    method = "mle", 
    start=list(a=alfa_est, b=beta_est))

where alfa_est and beta_est are the estimated values using MoM.
I use denscomp function to present the histogram and the adjusted density:
denscomp(rez_gumbel, main = "Fitted Gumbel f(x)", 
    xlab = "Q", ylab = "f(x)", 
    xlim = c(0, 600), datacol = "lightgrey", legendtext = "Gumbel")

But I want to impose the number of bins in histograms. Is it possible?

Just pass breaks = seq(min(q), max(q), length.out = 7) to denscomp? Look at the documentation of ... in help("denscomp").

Thank you. Only works when plotstyle = "ggplot". If plotstyle = "graphics" it draws but with error and warning message "Error in legend(x = xlegend, y = ylegend, bty = "n", legend = legendtext,  :
unused argument (breaks = c(47.5, 117.583333333333, 187.666666666667, 257.75, 327.833333333333, 397.916666666667, 468))
In addition: Warning message:
In plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) :
"breaks" is not a graphical parameter"

When I tested with breaks = 12 it worked for base graphics.

This code worked for me:
plot.legend <- c( "Lognormal", "Gamma", "Normal", "Weibull") 
num_bins <- 60 
density_plots <- list(
denscomp(list(fln, fg, fn, fw), n = num_bins, legendtext = c("Lognormal", "Gamma", "Normal", "Weibull"),
fitcol = c("darkblue", "#56B4E9", "#FC4E07", "#009E80"), fitlwd = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5),
fitlty = 1, xlab = expression(CV), plotstyle = "ggplot") +
geom_line(alpha = 0.7) +
theme_minimal() +
theme(text = element_text(family = "serif"), legend.position = "bottom")


When I ran your code, I got the error Error: object 'fln' not found. For the benefit of others (like myself) who have no experience using the denscomp() function, it would be useful if you updated your answer to include all the data and libraries required to make it run. Although it discusses creating questions, this link has some really useful guidance regarding how to share example data. Thanks.
